# Performing queries to find the triangle with the largest perimeter from an array of given side.

Tags: geometry, algorithms, triangles

We are given an array of numbers.We will be performing 2 types of querier:-

```
1)Find the triangle with the maximum perimeter in a given interval (l,r).
2)Update the array element at the given index i to a new given value x.
```

Example:-

1. We are given a[] = 3,1,8,9,7.We will be performing 4(q) queries in
   total.The first query is to find the maximum perimeter in the
   interval (1,5).So, we would return 24 as the maximum possible
   perimeter of the triangle in the range (1,5) is 24(8+9+7).
2. The second query is to update the value at index 2 to 12.So, now our array becomes a[] = 3,12,8,9,7.
3. The third query is to find the maximum perimeter in the interval (1,3) i.e from the array elements 3,1,8.We can't form any triangle from these elements.Hence, we return 0.

---

Now I have come up with an O(q*nlogn) approach by first sorting the elements for each query but was wondering if there is another better way.I was thinking of applying square root decomposition or segment trees but am not sure.

Comment: What do you call a triangle in this context ? Are your triangles flat ?Otherwise, where are the $x$ and $y$ coordinates ?

Comment: How you decide in Q2 to update value 1 with 12?

Comment: We just have to see if a triangle can be formed from the given sides in the given range.If yes, then we have to return the maximum perimeter of the triangle that can be formed.There is no used ot x and u coordinates.

Comment: @Moti It will be given by the user.All the ranges in the first query and the index and the new value in the second query will be given by the user.

Comment: Could you answer my question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I did.We simply have to check if any 3 numbers of the array can form a triangle.If their are multiple such numbers, then we have to return the triangle with the maximum perimeter.We don't need any x or y coordinates.

Comment: I understand only now that you mean that the numbers are (potential) **side lengthes** of a triangle, whereas I thought that there are coordinates. You should say it in your text ! It is not evident.

Comment: @JeanMarie Now that you understand this question, do you have ideas as to how to solve it?

Comment: A flagger says this is related to a currently running [codechef contest](https://www.codechef.com/MARCH18A/problems/PSHTRG). Locking. Flag when the contest is over.